# ftp while do error

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Anyone can help what will be the problem?

```
   Host='192.153.222.1'
   User='ftpuser'
   passwd='apple'
   logfile='a.log'

   while :; do
   ftp -n -p -v $HOST < example.script >> $logfile
   grep -qF "Connected" $logfile &&
   grep -qF "File successfully transferred" $logfile && break
   done

   quote USER $USER
   quote PASS $PASSWD
```

example.script contains

```
    put example.txt
```

The error is

./example.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes:

- You missed the closing quote in:

  Host='192.153.222.1'
- Use a single `<`, otherwise it's an "here document" in:

  ftp -n -p -v "$HOST" < example.script >> "$logfile"

Comment: >egrep: a.log: No such file or directory
>egrep: a.log: No such file or directory every time, why?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1656 2012-11-28 03:29 /tmp/a.log but after stops, must u crtl+z to quit

Comment: @Smithis, Sorry, we're not psychics, if you don't give us **all** the information we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `<<` in this line?

```
ftp -n -p -v $HOST << example.script >> $logfile
```

Change it to

```
ftp -n -p -v $HOST < example.script >> $logfile
```

It will work :-)

Comment: >egrep: a.log: No such file or directory
>egrep: a.log: No such file or directory every time, why?

Comment: Is a.log ever created in 7th line?

Comment: Its not normal. insert some `echo` in your code and see when this error exactly raised. Also edit the 8th and 9th lines temporary like this:
grep -qF "Connected" $logfile {NEW_LINE_HERE}
echo X {NEW_LINE_HERE}
grep -qF "File successfully transferred" $logfile

Comment: in logfile seems server cant accept the pass:530 You aren't logged in
Passive mode refused.

Comment: grep: a.log: No such file or directory
x
same problem

Comment: edit the 4th line as it: logfile='/tmp/a.log' and add this after 7th line: ls -l /tmp/a.log

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1656 2012-11-28 03:29 /tmp/a.log but after stops, must use crtl+z to quit

Comment: roll back all changes except the 4th line changes. it should be work like charm.

Comment: I think we can't complete your code here, also you haven't enough reputation to start a chat, so let me to end this discussion. Hope to success.