# shell syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Anyone can help me what will be the problem? login name and password is from .netrc. , < before example.script wont work

```
  #!/bin/bash
  HOST='192.163.3.3'
  FILE="a.txt"

  while :; do
      ftp -p -v -i $HOST << example.script >> a.log
      grep -qF "Connected" a.log &&
      grep -qF "File successfully transferred" a.log && break
  done

  exit 0
```

example.script contains

```
 put $FILE
 quit
```

And the error is:

```
 ./example.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

---

I got this while I'm using `sh -vx` on my script:

```
  while :; do
  ftp -p -v -i $HOST < example.script >> a.log
  grep -qF "Connected" a.log &&
  grep -qF "File successfully transferred" a.log && break
  done
  + :
  + ftp -p -v -i 192.163.3.3
  + grep -qF Connected a.log
  grep: a.log: No such file or directory
  + :
  + ftp -p -v -i 192.163.3.3
  + grep -qF Connected a.log
  grep: a.log: No such file or directory
  + :
```

*Note that this code fixes the problem (using `<` instead of `<<` for the input redirection).  The script file is given as `exaple.script` instead of `example.script`.*

Comment: It seems you always make the same type of mistakes! You already made the same mistake 2 days ago in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600009/ftp-while-do-error

Comment: if i use < i got error: grep: a.log: No such file or directory grep: a.log: No such file or directory grep

Comment: Start your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` when debugging it.

Comment: And perhaps you want `> a.log 2>&1` and you might want to use `ncftp` or `wget` or `curl`

Comment: the result is on my 2nd comment

Comment: It's funny that your message says line 15 and your code does not extend to line 15.  That's irksome; please get the exact error from the code you show, not an approximation from some variant.

Comment: That is all my script, I got the grep: a.log: No such file or directory error, no more syntax now. While im debugging it see my 2nd comment

Comment: I don't see any way the command `ftp ... >> a.log` wouldn't have created `a.log`, which means that the `grep` command shouldn't complain that it doesn't exist. If you didn't have permission to create `a.log`, the `ftp` command would have failed. Could there be some funny characters in your script; for example, could you be creating `a.log\r` rather than `a.log`? (Are you on Cygwin?) Add `ls -l a.log` after the `ftp` command and see what happens.

Comment: The 2 greps must be at least in one line. That was the problem is. Thx all for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your here document `<<` which has nothing to do here! Instead, you mean:

```
ftp -p -v -i $HOST < example.script >> a.log
```

Comment: grep: a.log: No such file or directory
grep: a.log: No such file or directory
grep: a.log: No such file or directory Another problem :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to **close** your *here-doc* :

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='192.163.3.3'
FILE="a.txt"

while :; do
    ftp -p -v -i $HOST <<EOF example.script >> a.log
    grep -qF "Connected" a.log &&
         grep -qF "File successfully transferred" a.log && break
done
EOF
```

`<<` open a *here-doc*

Comment: But then you need to close the `while` loop too.

Comment: dont work :/ ./example.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: That's unlikely to be the solution; it shouldn't have been a here-doc in the first place. `<<` was a typo for `<`.